# Create Json web token for DeviceCheck

Tags: python, ios, apple-push-notifications, jwt

Currently, I have written this code to create a JWT for server communication for the DeviceCheck API. I get back from apple the status of 'Unable to verify authorization token'. Any idea on how to fix?

```
import jwt
import uuid
import time
import json


def generateToken(certificate, keyID, teamID):
    ALGORITHM = 'ES256'
    token = jwt.encode(
    {
        'iss': teamID,
        'iat': time.time()
    },
    certificate,
    algorithm= ALGORITHM,
    headers={
        'alg': ALGORITHM,
        'kid': keyID,
        }
    )
    return token

def generateDeviceCheckApplePayload(device_token):
    millis = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    payload = {
    "device_token" : device_token,
    "transaction_id" : str(uuid.uuid4()),
    "timestamp" : millis,
    }
    payload = json.dumps(payload).encode('utf-8')
    return payload

def verifyDeviceWithApple(device_token):
    auth_token = generateToken(settings.CERTIFICATE, 
        settings.KEY_ID, settings.TEAM_ID)
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + str(auth_token),
    }
    data = generateDeviceCheckApplePayload(device_token)
    response = requests.post('https://' + settings.HOST + '/v1/validate_device_token', headers=headers, data=data)
    print(response.text)
    return True
```

Comment: can you please submit an answer if you figured out a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you need to make sure your Apple ID has been paid for